# passing data with two activity using sharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hy, I'm writing an application for a project. I'm trying to pass data between two activities. I tried to use the SharedPreference but it's doesn't work. The output send me always " ".

I post the two function below.

function for send data:

```
 public void SaveUser(FirebaseUser user){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(TEXT, user.getDisplayName());
    }
```

function for get data:

```
 public String ReturnCreatorName(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "");

        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot `editor.commit();`

```
public void SaveUser(FirebaseUser user){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TEXT, user.getDisplayName());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes